# Lambda expressions and how to combine them?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics, lambda

How can I combine two lambda expressions into one using an OR ?

I have tried the following but merging them requires me to pass parameters into the **Expression.Invoke** calls, however I want the value passed into the new lambda to be passed onto each child-lambda..

```
Expression<Func<int, bool>> func1 = (x) => x > 5;
Expression<Func<int, bool>> func2 = (x) => x < 0;
//Combines the lambdas but result in runtime error saying I need to pass in arguments
//However I want the argument passed into each child lambda to be whatever is passed into the new main lambda
Expression<Func<int, bool>> lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<int, bool>>(Expression.Or(Expression.Invoke(func1), Expression.Invoke(func2)));

 //The 9 should be passed into the new lambda and into both child lambdas
 bool tst = lambda.Compile().Invoke(9);
```

Any ideas how to combine two lambda expressions into one and have the arguments of the child lambdas be that of the parent ?

Comment: When you say "combine", what is it that you realy want to happen? Say that the argument passed is `7` - `func1` will return true, and `func2` will return false. What do you want the combination to return?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The best way I found to learn expressions, is to take a look at the source code of [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx).

When you want to combine multiple your statements, you can:

```
Expression<Func<int, bool>> func1 = (x) => x > 5;
Expression<Func<int, bool>> func2 = (x) => x > 10;

var invocation = Expression.Invoke(func2, func1.Parameters.Cast<Expression>());
var expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<int, bool>>(Expression.OrElse(func1.Body, invocation), func1.Parameters);
```

The `Expression.Invoke` creates an InvocationExpression that applies the parameters to your `func2`.

In fact, PredicateBuilder may be everything you need.

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<int>();
predicate = predicate.Or(x => x > 5);
predicate = predicate.Or(x => x > 10);
```

I would revise "`x > 5` or `x > 10`", seems like an odd thing to OR.

Hope that helps.

Comment: 'Expression.Lamda' is missing a 'b', so should be .Expression.Lambda'

Comment: `Expression.Invoke` is not supported by Linq to Entities by the way. So although this will compile to IL. It will not compile to SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Sound interesting ... I don't know much about lambda expression, but I found [this article](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx). Under *PredicateBuilder Source Code* is an example for *or* that works for me:

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T>(
                      this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
                      Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2 )
{
  var invExpr = Expression.Invoke( expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression>() );
  return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
      ( Expression.OrElse( expr1.Body, invExpr ), expr1.Parameters );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do:

```
Func<int, bool> func1 = (x) => x > 5;
Func<int, bool> func2 = (x) => x > 10;

List<Func<int, bool>> funcs = new List<Func<int, bool>> { func1, func2 };

var value = 7;

Console.WriteLine(funcs.Any(x => x(value))); // OR
Console.WriteLine(funcs.All(x => x(value))); // AND
```

?

Saves messing about with 3rd party libraries.

Comment: Problem is i want to keep these in an expression tree, so they are parsed by entity framework...

Comment: Fair enough, my suggestion probably isn't that viable then

Answer (score -2):

** edit: oops read over the OR thing, updated it ***

Hi,

Not sure if you just want to call them seperatley or you want to combine them from an academic point of view.

You can just call them like this:

```
bool OR(int i1, Func<int, bool> f1, Func<int, bool> f2){
    return f1(i1) || f2(i1);
}
```

That will do the trick.

or you can rewrite that as

```
bool MyOR = (i1, f1, f2) => f1(i1) || f2(i1);
```

And when you're qurious, create an expression from that and look at that. (doing this by hand, don;t have VS here now, so please be easy on my typos)

```
Expression<Func<int, Func<int, bool>, Func<int, bool>, bool>> exprOR = 
(i1, f1, f2) => f1(i1) || f2(i1);
```

If you want to look at the anatomy of the expression, you can look at this article i wrote: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WpfExpressionTree.aspx

Just pass the expression to the apadater and see how it;s built up.

Regards Gert-Jan