# Where or (not and) with list of expressions c#

Tags: c#, lambda, filtering, where-clause, iqueryable

I got the following code

```
public class Personnel {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int OrganizationalUnitId { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
}

private List<Expression<Func<Personnel, bool>>> personnelFilter;

public void AddFilter(Expression<Func<Personnel, bool>> filter)
{
    this.personnelFilter.Add(filter);
}

public IEnumerable<Personnel> GetResult()
{
    IQueryable<Personnel> personnel = Store.Instance.Query<Personnel>();
    foreach(var filter in this.personnelFilter)
    {
        personnel = personnel.Where(filter);
    }

    return personnel;
}
```

It now uses AND, cause it appends the Where clause to an already filtered query. But I don't want to add it as AND but as OR.

So let's say i add the filter:

```
model.AddFilter(a => a.FirstName == "Test")
model.AddFilter(a => a.FirstName == "More")

// Or adding something stupid like:
model.AddFilter(a => a.OrganizationalUnit == 1)
model.AddFilter(a => a.OrganizationalUnit == 1)
```

I want the following query:

```
WHERE Firstname == "Test" || Firstname == "More"
```

without doing:

```
model.AddFilter(a => a.FirstName == "Test" || a.FirstName == "More")
```

Is this possible? In other words, I got a list with expressions, and I want to OR them in stead of AND in the where clause, but I cant find a way to make it work. Any idea's?

Comment: What is `Expression<Personnel, bool>`? According to MSDN it does not exist (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb506649.aspx). I assume this must me `Func<Personnel, bool>`?

Comment: @Martin Mulder, corrected it, I created an example on the fly.

Comment: You said you tried Expression.Or but it failed. Can you tell why it failed?

Comment: Lack of knowledge, see answer below, it was of the wrong type, but you can convert it to a Func<T, bool> with ease.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this: (code did not work)

This seems a backwards, but is just the inversion logic: A || B is equal to !(!A && !B). Except() is the negated version of Where(), so you should be fine.

---

Edit: I have worked and it seems you have to combine them properly like this:

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Combine_Or<T>(
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
{
    var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke(expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression>());
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
          (Expression.OrElse(expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
}
```

Basically taken from here: [Lambda expressions and how to combine them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288076/lambda-expressions-and-how-to-combine-them)

My complete testing code: http://pastebin.com/cLXi77pf

Comment: the database(engine) should simplify the expression and !(!A && !B) should become A || B, so I guess this is a great solution :)

Comment: ... Except only accepts IENumerable<Personnel>, no expression.

Comment: Dee my edit, you need to modify the expression tree to properly combine the lambdas.